# Python search for file ending

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a python script to search all `.avi` file in the current folder, and write their names in a file for later processing.

However I only get an empty file, even if I have a `.avi` in my folder.

Here's my code:

```
import sh

f = open("film.txt", "w")

ending = [".avi", ".mp4"]
lsa = sh.ls("-a")
for i in lsa:
    if i in "*.avi":
        print(i, file=f)

f.close()
```

Comment: `'a.avi' in '*.avi'` returns `False` to me. Are you sure this logic is correct? (Idk if this works in python 3, I use python2.7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open file via "with":

```
with open("film.txt", "w") as f:
    for root, _, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith((".avi", ".mp4")):
                f.write(file)
```

Answer (score 3):

`in` doesn't do such pattern matching. Assuming `i` is a string, just use

```
i.endswith('.avi')
```

But for gods sake, don't call a string variable `i`.

Or to check for multiple endings at once (thanks @msvalkon for the reminder):

```
i.endswith((".avi", ".mp4"))
```

And you could use Python's `glob` module which does come with such pattern functionality:

```
import glob
with open("film.txt", "w") as f:
    for filename in glob.glob("*.avi"):
        print(filename, file=f)
```

Comment: Maybe add that `str.endswith` accepts a tuple of items to match so as per the example the OP has given: `i.endswith((".avi", ".mp4"))`

Comment: @msvalkon Thanks, I overlooked that as it wasn't in the text or the main code. Added it now.

Comment: You can use `iglob` to avoid building a list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh wow, even Python 3 has that. I never used it and probably never will, as I don't fancy that `i` and my tolerance for number of files in one directory is around 100. And I claim if someone has a problem with `glob.glob`, then they have too many files in one place and *deserve* to suffer :-P

Answer (score 1):

file writes should be done like this:

```
f.write(i)
```

but you probably also have a problem with `if i in "*.avi":`

so your code would be

```
import sh

f = open("film.txt", "w")

ending = [".avi", ".mp4"]
lsa = sh.ls("-a")
for i in lsa:
    for end in ending:
        if i.endswith(end): 
            print("found one {}".format(i))
            f.write(i)
f.close()
```

And now the nice version:

```
import glob, itertools
patterns = ["*.avi","*.mp4"]
with open("film.txt", "w") as ofile:
    for fl in itertools.chain.from_iterable(glob.glob(pattern) for pattern in patterns):
        ofile.write(fl + "\n")
```

Comment: @Pentagon98: try the nice version. I don't trust your `ls` thingy

Comment: @Pentagon98: also make sure you run this in a dir that actually has these kind of files

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the built in `glob` module which does exactly what you want:

```
import glob

with open("film.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(glob.glob("*.avi") + glob.glob("*.mp4")))
```

`glob.glob` searches for files that match a certain pattern. If you use what I wrote it will search for files in the current directory which have `.avi` or `.mp4` file extensions

Note the use of a context manager (`with open(...)`) instead of `f = open(...)` and `f.close()`. This is more pythonic.

Also, I used `\n` joining to skip the `for` loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, `writelines` doesn't appear to add line endings.

Answer (score 1):

What `if i in "*.avi"` is doing is asking "is `i` a substring of `'*.avi'`"?  That is not a glob-matching operation.

The simplest solution is probably to use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) instead of `sh`.

```
for i in glob.glob('*.avi') + glob.glob('*.mp4'):
    …
```

Comment: check out my solution which doesn't use a `for` loop

Comment: It's asking not just those five, try `"av" in "*.avi"`.

Answer (score 0):

modified the answer of Rain Lee a bit.

1st) define a function:

```
def search_ending(path, extension):
    for root, dir, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            if os.path.splitext(filename)[-1] == extension:
                yield os.path.join(root, filename)
```

2nd) call that function and put the results in a list:

```
ext_list = list(search_pos(os.getcwd(), '.jpg'))
```

3rd) you could display it

```
for line in ext_list:
        print('\n'+ line)
```